# I need to position my movie over my Flash website

Tags: css, flash, html

I need to make myself walk in front of my Flash website.  All I have is a movie with a white background.  Does anyone know the process?  Using Flash 8.

Comment: If you are trying to place one movie over another, you can load it on top of the first one. No css hacks required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about alpha encoding the video?  You can use the Flash Media Encoder to turn that white background into a transparent background and then load that video (I'm assuming you have a video of yourself walking onto a white background?) over your swf to get the effect you're looking for.

The encoder should come with your install of Flash 8.

Comment: You are correct, it's a well lit white background.  Thanks a lot, I hope this works.  I've never used the encoder, but this will give me a reason to play with it.
 
 
www.customized-templates.com

Answer (score 1):

Working on the assumption that both movies are flash, Amarghosh is correct the best way would be to load the movie of yourself over the top of the existing movie.

So you would do this inside your flash environment as opposed to using css.